# Enabling Opcache Not Working

Tags: php, opcache

I am trying to enable Opcache, but for some reason, after editing my php.ini file and restarting apache (even rebooting the server), it still does not get enabled. Running a test I can see that that the php files location:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Within that file I have added:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

The location of the zend extension was defined by locate opcache.so. This did not work. I then noticed that php was loading an additional file /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini. In that file it looks like:

```
; configuration for php ZendOpcache module
; priority=05
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

However, after restarting apache it still will not enable. The following is in my phpinfo() output:

```
Opcode Caching  Disabled
```

How can I get it to enable?

Comment: Ages later, I have the same issue, no answers solve. :(

Comment: I ran in exactly [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47622243/php-opcache-variables-not-set-correctly)... and still no answer...

Comment: i posted the answer below - : hope it solves https://stackoverflow.com/a/75528073/10518289

Answer (score 3):

In the output from `phpinfo()`, have a look at the `.ini` files listed under:

> Additional .ini files parsed

There may be something like

`/usr/local/php5/php.d/20-extension-opcache.ini`

Make sure `opcache.enable=1` is set in this file.

Comment: Thank you sir. This was driving me crazy and just like that it worked, followed by running sudo apachectl restart

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the ini file location

```
cat /etc/php.d/10-opcache.ini
```

Comment: Worked for me in ` /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

If everything else fails, you could try:

```
sudo yum install php-opcache
```

Solved the issue on my PHP 7.2 version for Fedora.

Turns out I didn't have opcache installed (a key giveaway was the lack of a .ini file on the "Additional .ini files parsed" section of phpinfo()).

Answer (score 0):

check the [opcache] section in php.ini

```
[opcache]
; Determines if Zend OPCache is enabled
opcache.enable=0
```

Comment: Nope, that was commented out. Even after uncommenting and setting to 1, I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Common Misunderstanding

Theres settings for PHP Cli and PHP-FPM

What you are seeing is that Opcache is disabled for CLI

Create a php file in your server (should be accessible from web). i named it phpi.php, add the following:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Open it from a browser http(s)://your_ip_or_domain/path/to/phpi.php

Scroll down and look for Zend `OPcache`

if you see Opcode Caching up and running, then its enabled

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First do this

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
```

then

```
sudo pecl install zendopcache-beta
```