# php opcache variables not set correctly

Tags: php, opcache

I'm trying to set the variables to setup opcahe in my php.ini file.
phpinfo says:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) 
Path    /etc/php/7.0/fpm
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini 
Scan this dir for additional .ini files   /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d 
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
```

> /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
...
```

And /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, contains:

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.save_comments=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=1
opcache.file_cache=/tmp;
```

When I look in phpinfo results for opcache, I see:

```
opcache.enable  On  On
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.max_accelerated_files   2000    2000
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 4   4
opcache.memory_consumption  64  64
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
```

Does anyone know why it does not take my variables???

Comment: Did you restart Apache / FPM after changing the values to pick up the new settings?

Comment: Yes @NicoHaase, I restarted multiple times, and even rebooted the server (actually it's a rapsberrypi 3)

Answer (score 0):

Solved but I don't really know how.
I just (re)installed php7-intl and php7-sqlite3 for other problems then the error messages concerning opcache disappeared